# Content Security Policy error, without any inline javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I've been seeing this error while I try to load my chrome extension:

`Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com".`

Here is part of my **manifest.json**:

```
...

 "background": {
 "scripts": ["launcher.js"]
     },
"options_page": "options.html",
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": [
"tabs", "notifications", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"

...
```

In whole of my javascript I've only been communicating with https://ajax.googleapis.com and I've ensured with the **Network** tab of **Inspect views**.

And I've verified all my javascript code sits inside my **.js** file only. (And yes I'm using **addEventListener()** wherever necessary.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** Showing code responsible for the error (asked by Rob)
This is the only place where I'm communicating with ANY server:

```
....
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=" + storyCount + "&callback=?",
        data: {
                q: link,
                output: "json_xml"
             },
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             if (data.responseStatus == 200) {
                //process JSON
              }
....
```

Comment: Can you show the code which causes the error?

Comment: Rob, I've updated the post to show you the piece of code that is performing the communication with the server. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: `&callback=?` is the problem. That initiates JSONP. JSONP = Append `<script>` tag with `src` attribute set, often from a different domain.

Comment: Rob, I don't know if you intended me to give it a try removing the `&callback=?` which I did, without luck still.

Comment: The problem is really laid therin. Compare https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1&output=json_xml&q=1&callback=foo and https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1&output=json_xml&q=1&callback=foo. What new error are you getting?

Comment: Did you mean with and without `&callback=?` in the URL? I see exactly the very same error in both cases: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com".

Answer (score 2):

With the Change from Manifest Version 1 to 2 . Chrome Extension do not allow you to use inline javascript. You need to place all your javascript inside a .JS file and include it inside the html page.

Also remove all onclick, onchange,onsubmit to eventlistner events.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the input Dipesh008, my project does not have any inline JS code at all. All the bindings occur inside JS files referenced within HTML files. Yes, I am using manifest version 2. Here's the link to [HTML page](https://github.com/ideazinfinite/feader-rss-viewer/blob/master/news.html).

Answer (score 0):

This error message has nothing to do with the requests you do to other servers - it is about inline scripts. If you don't have any inline scripts then most likely it comes up because somewhere you are creating code dynamically, by means of `eval()`, `new Function()` or similar. For example, jQuery will do that to parse JSON if it doesn't find `JSON.parse()` method (in Chrome this method should normally be available however). From the info you gave here it is impossible to tell which code is responsible for the error.

Regardless of that, you should definitely not use JSONP as [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) correctly noted in the comments. JSONP will execute code from a remote server in the context of your extension which is inherently insecure - theoretically it would only call the callback but practically it could also do something malicious. You should use JSON instead (data being downloaded and parsed, no remote code execution) and remove `ajax.googleapis.com` from your Content Security Policy.

Comment: Thanks @wladimir-palant for shedding light on the issue. I guess I assumed `$.ajax()` to be the culprit since the error was referencing it too but now realized its nothing but my CSP statement as is. I can see my JS doing some dynamic code creation possibly with jQuery, something I can't get rid of. This being the case, what would you advise/recommend? Shall I tweak my CSP to allow inline code? Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot allow inline code. Ask a new question and explain why you are creating code dynamically - it should be possible to avoid that.

Comment: Here are the files I've been referencing: [news.js](https://github.com/ideazinfinite/feader-rss-viewer/blob/master/news.js) and [options.js](https://github.com/ideazinfinite/feader-rss-viewer/blob/master/options.js). Thanks in advance.